# Any way to use Hamcrest matchers in production code?

Tags: java, hamcrest

I'd like to use **hamcrest** as sugar framework to use in `if` statements, not in the unit tests with asserts, but in raw production code.

Something like

```
if ( isNotEmpty(name) ) return //....
```

or

```
if ( isEqual(name, "John")) return //...
```

Just like `AssertThat` but without throwing errors, just returning boolean.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's the [bool project](https://github.com/lordofthejars/bool) that provides the following syntax:

```
if(the(name, is(equalTo("Alex")))) {
...
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's really impressive!

Comment: IMHO bool project is a bit overkill for a simple method "the". Even though it provides additional matchers, but these are just duplicates of Hamcrest ones (like allOf, anyOf, either, both, etc)

Answer (score 6):

It's just Java, it's up to you what you choose to do with it.  The [Hamcrest homepage](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/) says:

> Provides a library of matcher objects (also known as constraints or predicates) allowing 'match' rules to be defined declaratively, to be used in other frameworks. Typical scenarios include testing frameworks, mocking libraries and UI validation rules.
>
> Note: ***Hamcrest it is not a testing library: it just happens that matchers are very useful for testing***.

There is also [a page on the other frameworks](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/UsesOfHamcrest) that use Hamcrest.

Comment: Agree, I just need a working example, how to use matchers without assertThat

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `matches(value)` method of any `Matcher` instance.

```
if (equalTo("John").matches(name)) { ... }
```

To improve the readability, create your own helper method similar to `assertThat`.

```
public static <T> boolean checkThat(T actual, Matcher<? super T> matcher) {
    return matcher.matches(actual);
}

...

if (checkThat(name, equalTo("John"))) { ... }
```

If you come up with a better name than `checkThat` such as `ifTrueThat`, please add it in a comment. :)

Answer (score 5):

Following up on David's answer, we are currently doing exactly this, and our helper method is named "the()". This leads to code like:

```
if(the(name, is(equalTo("John")))) {...}
```

which gets a little bit lisp-y at the end, but makes it very readable even for clients.